# Ordering a short list of images with HTML input elements

Tags: html, sort, ordering, sorting, order

I want to create a quick survey in [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://requester.mturk.com/) for an image sorting task, say from brighter to darker images. I know that I can even create an external website and design a drag-and-drop interface but these images can be quite big (around 800px by 600px) and dragging one with autoscrolling up and down without seeing the overview of what has been answered so far can be as annoying as sorting a big list. Also, this is probably a one-time task so I opt for the built-in web interface which allows HTML input elements

The most obvious solution to me is a *small drop-down list for ordering* (`1st, 2nd, 3rd, ...`) per image at the bottom. The user can drag up to see the images which are coded with `A, B, C, ...` and go down to reply one by one or remember a partial order, answer, and repeat until done. This can be similarly implemented by an array of radio buttons but will take more screen real estate (and probably more dragging.)

[image]

It is possible that two images may be chosen for the same order as these drop-down lists are not dynamic. I think I will just reject those answers.

Is this good for 6-10 images? If it is really bad, can you suggest an alternative or should I only go for drag-and-drop?

Answer (score 1):

If the main issue with drag-and-drop is the size of the images and lack of getting an overview, using thumbnails might be an option.

Comment: Do you mean putting thumbnails in a row below all images? Then it will not be much better than a row of drop-down lists besides that it removes the possibility that images are placed in the same order, right?

Comment: The specific layout is depending on the context. If the solution is fairly 'stand-alone' and doesn't need to take into account any mannerisms, I would probably have a list to the left containing the thumbnail previews as a sortable ordered list, then use the right part of the screen to show the fully sized images. As you sort the left-hand list, the images to the right would rearrange to sync up with the previews.

This would assume that you can use a mouse and don't have to  be able to do the sorting with a keyboard alone.